# Swift: [NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am building a Cocoa app for production and when I create an `NSViewController` for routing without `NSStoryboard` instantiate, I got the error like below.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: ContentFully.AnotherController in bundle (null).
```

Actually I solved my problem via using an `NSViewController` to adding `NSStoryboard` but I would like to learn what is going on when I call it programmatically and why did crash?

> Working scenario

```
let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Dashboard", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialController() as! AnotherController
```

> Crashed scenario

```
let vc = AnotherController()
self.view.window?.contentViewController = vc
```

Even if I create a class fully programmatically and non-relational with `NSStoryboard` I could not use it when I change the `contentViewController`. Is it necessary to search every controller in `NSBundle` for `Swift`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very simple working version would be:

```
import Cocoa

class AnotherController: NSViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 270.0))
        let label = NSTextField(labelWithString: "Another Controller")
        view.addSubview(label)
    }
    
}
```

I can call that from my first controller using the code you say crashes and get the expected result.

```
@IBAction func replaceMe(_ sender: Any) {
    let vc = AnotherController()
    self.view.window?.contentViewController = vc
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I've tried all of the ways to create a class (programmatically, with overriding `loadView()`, or just implement a custom `init()` methods ). If it's possible can you provide an example to create a controller for my situation?

Comment: @elia  Answer changed to show code.  (Obviously it needs more work for sizing and constraints.  In the end, a storyboard implementation would probably be simpler.)

Comment: yup, thank you Phillip. I learned that I must use `loadView` for using programmatically purpose when I use `NSStoryboard` + `Programmatically` approach.